# The difference between boto3.client and pymysql.connect

Tags: python-3.x, boto3, amazon-rds, pymysql, amazon-sagemaker

I am the novice in using AWS-RDS-mysql, Now I have a problem when connecting this database

Here I have two ways to connect to my AWS-RDS-mysql, one is to use 'boto3' package and another is 'pymysql' package.

For boto3, four paramaters are required, they are:

```
1) type='rds', 
2) region,
3) aws_access_key_id
4) aws_secret_access_key
```

The function I use is:

```
boto3.client(type, region, aws_access_key_id=key_id, aws_secret_access_key=access_key)
```

For pymysql, I need 5 parameters, they are:

```
1) host = "databaseinstancename.cxxxxxxxxxx.ca-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
2) port = 3306
3) dbname = "xxx"
4) user = "admin"
5) password = "ssssss"
```

The method I use is:

```
pymysql.connect(host, user=user, port=port, passwd=password, db=dbname)
```

All of them could connect to the database from my pycharm successfully.

My question is

1) what's the difference between the first method(using boto3) and the second one(using pymysql)? There are must be something difference because I provide two different kinds of information to connect.

2) When I use jupyter notebook in AWS sagemaker to edit python3 code to try to connect to the database, I find only the first method(using boto3) could work, the second method(using pymysql) cannot connect successfully with a error saying that 'time out'. Why does this happen when one method could be accessible to the database but another one fails?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) what's the difference between the first method(using boto3) and the second one(using pymysql)? There are must be something difference because I provide two different kinds of information to connect.

- `boto3` is used to manage your db instances in RDS service. You use to, e.g. create your mysql db instance with read replicas, setup security groups for the db instance, enable public access, and many more.
- `pymysql` is used to actually connect to your mysql database, add data to it, select data from it etc.

> 2) When I use jupyter notebook in AWS sagemaker to edit python3 code to try to connect to the database, I find only the first method(using boto3) could work, the second method(using pymysql) cannot connect successfully with a error saying that 'time out'. Why does this happen when one method could be accessible to the database but another one fails?

`pymysql` time outs as probably you haven't configured security group for your DB data instance and/or not enabled public access.

Answer (score 0):

`boto3` is *specifically* an AWS library. It'll use your AWS access credentials and AWS APIs to find information about the parameters you've provided.

Behind the scenes, it very well may use a more standard library such as `pymysql` or `sqlalchemy` or others to connect to some RDS instance. (Although, I see you didn't specify any instance instance of RDS in a region, so its hard to know if you really connected to anything instead of simply just creating a `BotoClient` instance)

The timeouts could simply be due to the fact you're giving wrong credentials or the network is not configured to connect between those environments.

---

In other words - the difference is that `pymsql` would work for **any** MySQL database